# How to printf different locale?

Tags: c, printf, setlocale, windows-1255

In C, after setting a new locale with`setlocale(LC_ALL, "Hebrew")`, I could print the new local name (Hebrew.Israel.1255), but couldn't figure how to use the new locale's charset, since`printf(%c, 240)` printed '?' instead of a hebrew letter([1255 map](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/windows/windows-1255.html)).

.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` format specifier always prints a byte with the given value. It has nothing to do with the locale. You should use something like `printf("%lc", 0x05D0);` which will print a wide character (which is encoded in Unicode on all sane implementations) in the current locale's encoding.